# Blender 2.80 Subdivision Surface Modifier has no effect

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

The Subdivion Surface Modifier in Blender 2.80 on Ubuntu is not working for me.
I create a cylinder, grid, cube or UV sphere, then apply the modifier, nothing happens. When I press "apply" the rror message is: "Modifier returned error, skipping apply".

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: silly question, but did you actually click subdivide so that the object is subdivided once? You'll have 3 options that should increase in value view 1
Sculpt 2
render 2
quality 3 if you see that, then you can hit apply.

Comment: I think it is a bug in the Linux (Ubuntu) version of Blender 2.80. I looked at the same scene in Blender (basically, a subdivided cube), and on Windows it looks curved as expected whereas on Linux there is no subdivision.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu and can confirm this is present. I was hoping someone would be able to help.

Comment: The Ubuntu package is silently broken. You have to download from blender.org.

Answer (score 2):

Updating to version 2.81 Fixed this for me.

Comment: There is no 2.81 Ubuntu package. Like in my comment above, you have to directly download from blender.org.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did